# Can a wireless router get a virus?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a friend who has a linksys wireless router and is having problems with getting internet. Is there any way a wireless router can get a virus?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. There are more likely reasons why there'll be connection problems.

Comment: Just wondering, what makes you suspect it is the router?  Why not suspect the PC first?

Comment: Because there are many different PCs that are being affected. I personally don't think its the router its just that they were assuming it was the router so I wanted to disprove that first

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/446315/how-to-know-if-your-computer-is-hit-by-a-dnschanger-virus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While it's possible that a router can get a virus, it's very unlikely (in the realm of winning the lottery or falling off a donkey).

Your friend's router may need attention from a professional. Have the ISP check it out or see if you can get a replacement.

If you know what problems it's having, maybe we can help here. For that, we need a lot of information about the router and what you've tried.

---

EDIT: Resetting the router to factory defaults will eliminate any configuration issues or corruption (including alleged viruses), if you need to prove a point.

Comment: ok, thanks that was what I was thinking I am going to look into some more things first but if I can't make any headway I will add more info.

Comment: If you're trying to prove a point to your friend, do a hard reset and start from scratch. The reset will wipe it completely and eliminate any possible corruption of the firmware.

Comment: @Randolph ah... thanks, forgot about that option, I will definitely do that.

Comment: I agree with Randolph, just remember to backup the firmware before wiping it.  Good luck.

Comment: I've added my comment to the answer for factory reset.

Comment: I will have you know that falling off a donkey is incredibly easy.

Comment: Though I agree it's more likely config, it's a bit easier to get a malicious config than you lead on. The evil config may do dns poisoning, or mess with router tables, or ssl certs.  Luckily the factory reset will fix this too, so the common solution is Nuke From Orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

While not technically a virus, router poisoning could occur. If a malicious agent gains access to a router, it could change the default DNS to a malicious server that can then redirect your traffic however it sees fit.

But like Randolph has stated, Resetting to factory defaults should eliminate any issues.

Answer (score 0):

We had that happen to our Linkseye wireless router yesterday when we went to hook up a friend's laptop to our router to look up problems they were having in linking to the internet.

It immediately affected all our connected devices and it would not allow us to get back online – only to the CISCO router site. The friend's laptop evidently reconfigured our router but we couldn't get it to go back to factory defaults. We tried to press reset and reinstall the CD but nothing would happen.

Talking to their tech support – it allowed online chat – they offered to correct it for a fee (because I had gone past their 90 day warranty) so we declined and went out and bought a different brand router and re-established internet connection.

I am currently trying to use Norton to clean anything which may have contaminated our devices – but how can this friend's laptop be cleaned? I will not try to hook it back up through our router system again.

Comment: Welcome to SU - please post this as a separate question instead of tagging on to an existing question. Questions that have already had an answer accepted generally don't get much attention.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You've posted this as an **answer**, but it's **not** an attempt to answer the original poster's question, so it [may be removed soon](http://superuser.com/faq#deletion). If you have a **new** question, please ask it by clicking the [**Ask question**](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button.